# Modifying/Injecting CSS Style sheets in GeckoFX

Tags: css, vb.net, mozilla, geckofx

I am trying to manipulate Style Sheets through:

```
GeckoFXWebBrowser.Document.StyleSheets
```

as mentioned [here](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-2.0/wiki/GeckofxHelp), but clearing or adding any rules as mentioned there throwing exceptions related to JSContext, also I tried to use `nsIStyleSheetService` similarly to what mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service) as follows:

```
Dim SSS = Gecko.Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of Gecko.nsIStyleSheetService)("@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1")
Dim mUri = Gecko.IOService.CreateNsIUri("myCSSUri")
SSS.LoadAndRegisterSheet(mUri, Gecko.nsIDOMWindowUtilsConsts.USER_SHEET)
```

But this also throwing ambigious COM related exception.

I tried all this in DocumentCompleted event.

Any ideas what is wrong here? or how to accomplish task? (GeckoFX 29)

Comment: Ok I resolved the issue, I had to use `Gecko.Xpcom.GetService` instade of `Gecko.Xpcom.CreateInstance`, then everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Since the FAQ entry was written Firefox has had some security changes which is prolly the cause of the initial exceptions.

Check out the [Geckofx 29 unittests](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/src/eead77c1a7e2e8a483e5ca97fdcaa5291af8ad21/GeckofxUnitTests/GeckoStyleTests.cs?at=default) here in particular :

```
[Test]
public void GetCssRules_DoesNotThrowException()
{
    GeckoStyleSheet styleSheet = _browser.Document.StyleSheets.First();
    GeckoStyleSheet.StyleRuleCollection cssRules = null;
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { cssRules = styleSheet.CssRules; });
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { cssRules.Insert(0, "#blanc { color: white }"); });
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { cssRules.RemoveAt(0); });
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => { cssRules.Clear(); });
}
```

As for the second method using nsIStyleSheetService:

```
Dim mUri = Gecko.IOService.CreateNsIUri("myCSSUri")
```

Is likely to work better if you specify a valid uri. (eg. http://www.google.com)

Comment: Thank you for help, however I resolved the issue in a better way as you can see in my comment, also myCSSUri is just a replacment for a real uri.